# Why do links not open in new tab?

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, hyperlinks

Actually, I've noticed that when I click on an external link it leaves Stack Exchange and the new link opens. Dear StackExchange you have to take care of that and make links open in a new tab.

### Example :

click on this link : http://www.stackoverflow.com/

Comment: That's the behavior I get most places unless I shift-click on a link (Firefox/MacOS X).

Comment: Shouldn't this be tagged ([meta-tag:feature-request]) rather than ([meta-tag:bug])?

Comment: I don't get it, what exactly is the problem?

Comment: @Thomas if you click the link that i have mentioned for example, you'll never see math.stackexchange again and stackoverflow pop up.

Comment: Isn't that how links usually work? Do you want it to open in a new tab?

Comment: Yes, that's how logically links does work, but most of websites today provide new-tab links feature.

Comment: This feature request on meta.stackexchange is ([meta-tag:status-declined]): http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2275/make-links-posted-by-users-open-in-a-new-window

Comment: And you can't just set up your browser to do this for you? I just use my middle button to open a link in a new tab.

Comment: Give me one reason why does Stack Exchange not providing this "feature" and i will never consider this as a bug.

Comment: is it hard to use `<a href="" target="_blank"></a>` ?

Comment: @Antaraz: I still don't understand why you want external links to work like this. Again: can't you just use the middle-click option?

Comment: That's a UX, Most of websites using this "feature" why do i have to press control + mouse click while the website that i'm visiting can handle this for me by adding a target="_blank" propertie ?

Comment: @Antaraz: What is a UX?

Comment: and take into account that New Tab $\not =$ New Window

Comment: User Experience

Comment: I know that a new tab is not a new window. But I really do not any more tabs open. The point is that you eliminate the open of replacing the existing window with the external link. Normal behavior (AFAIK) is that a link replaces the current tab.

Comment: @Thomas why you need more tabs, I'm talking about stack exchange and the external links $1+1=2$ those are two tabs, i don't care about your other tabs actually.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14195/discussion-between-thomas-and-antaraz)

Answer (score 6):

It has already been pointed out in the comment that a similar s[uggestion from 2009 was declined](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2275/make-links-posted-by-users-open-in-a-new-window).

That said, I disagree with the proposal because I believe that should be handled in the browser. I would be (very) annoyed if I would get a new tab/windows every time I clicked an external link. As it is now I can navigate links exclusively using the mouse and if we implemented your suggestion I would have to reconfigure my browser or my middle-click option.

Also, I believe that most browsers will allow you to force a new tab with a middle-click, ctrl+click, shift+click or something like that.

Comment: That's in 2009 but now tabs can be pinned and they never annoying me.

Comment: This is our policy - we leave the decision on how to open links up to the user. (Personally, I tend to open all links, internal or external, in new tabs.)

Comment: @AnnaLear is that a reason or .. ?

Comment: @Antaraz My personal preference? Not a reason, just side information. The first sentence of my comment is the official reasoning that we currently have no plans to change.

Comment: Ok, actually you don't have to tag this as status-declined as you do without providing any reason, answer in the answers box and tell the world why you decline this.

Comment: @Antaraz Of course they need to tag it as status-declined as that is the status of the feature request. And there has been plenty of explanation for the reasons.

Answer (score 6):

I *strongly* hold the opinion that websites should not enforce their own idea of browsing on the user. Let the user browse how he wants, and let his browser handle the browsing.

In particular, any user who wants to open a link in a new tab can do so easily using the functionality of his browser.